# System-level approach to determining a library name for use with cdll.LoadLibrary

Tags: python, linux, ctypes, loadlibrary

According to the documentation,

> On Linux, it is *required to specify the filename* including the
>   extension to load a library, so attribute access can not be used to
>   load libraries. Either the LoadLibrary() method of the dll loaders
>   should be used, or you should load the library by creating an instance
>   of CDLL by calling the constructor:

I am using a set of python scripts that have been developed externally. They require a *rather* standard lib (`liblzma`) and use `LoadLibrary` from `ctypes` to load it--via a pathname.  My problem is that these scripts need to run on several different linux installs and potentially more in the future. *The full file name of the `liblzma` shared library, as well as it's location, varies from system to system.* I've done testing against the various lib versions and there have found no conflicts.

**What I really need** is a way to determine the base name of the *installed libs* in order to pass the appropriate name to `LoadLibrary`.

I've considered just using `ldconfig -p` to print existing libs and parsing the output to find the lib names.  Any other ideas?

I'm admittedly a bit out of my element here.  The problematic scripts are merely a required piece of a larger project.

Comment: I might be missing something basic, but what is wrong with `ctypes.util.find_library("lzma")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the library is in the loader search path you can specify it by relative name.

```
$ ls /usr/lib64/libXt.*
/usr/lib64/libXt.so.6.0.0

>>> ctypes.CDLL('libXt.so.6.0.0')
<CDLL 'libXt.so.6.0.0', handle 26b72b0 at 2723c90>
```

Comment: Good point!  It's this feature that I'd like to exploit.  The problem lies in the fact that the lib name is different on different machines.

Comment: Well that's a separate issue. Use the most likely name first, followed by the second, etc.

Comment: With dynamically linked executable code, the linker / loader can actually perform some automatic resolution of lib requirements WRT version and it surely knows where the libs are. I guess I'm after mimicking that here.  I know the linker / loader isn't employed--clearly the script is loading the lib.